# Add a duration to a moment (moment.js)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Moment version: 2.0.0

[After reading the docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/), I thought this would be straight-forward (Chrome console):

```
var timestring1 = "2013-05-09T00:00:00Z";
var timestring2 = "2013-05-09T02:00:00Z";
var startdate = moment(timestring1);
var expected_enddate = moment(timestring2);
var returned_endate = startdate.add(moment.duration(2, 'hours'));
returned_endate == expected_enddate  // false
returned_endate  // Moment {_i: "2013-05-09T00:00:00Z", _f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z", _l: undefined, _isUTC: false, _a: Array[7]…}
```

This is a trivial example, but I can't even get it to work. I feel like I'm missing something big here, but I really don't get it. Even this this doesn't seem to work:

```
startdate.add(2, 'hours')
    // Moment {_i: "2013-05-09T00:00:00Z", _f: "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss Z", _l: undefined, _isUTC: false, _a: Array[7]…}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**
My end goal is to make an binary status chart like the one I'm working on here:
http://bl.ocks.org/phobson/5872894

As you can see, I'm currently using dummy x-values while I work through this issue.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

I think you missed a key point in the documentation for `.add()`

> Mutates the original moment by adding time.

You appear to be treating it as a function that returns the immutable result.  Easy mistake to make.  :)

If you use the return value, it is the same actual object as the one you started with.  It's just returned as a convenience for method chaining.

You can work around this behavior by cloning the moment, [as described here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/).

Also, you cannot just use `==` to test.  You could format each moment to the same output and compare those, or you could just use the `.isSame()` method.

Your code is now:

```
var timestring1 = "2013-05-09T00:00:00Z";
var timestring2 = "2013-05-09T02:00:00Z";
var startdate = moment(timestring1);
var expected_enddate = moment(timestring2);
var returned_endate = moment(startdate).add(2, 'hours');  // see the cloning?
returned_endate.isSame(expected_enddate)  // true
```

Comment: I really appreciate the response, Matt. It clears up many things. Here's what I still can't get my head around: every representation of `returned_endate` that I know how to access is still at midnight, and not 2am. I need it to be 2am so that I can make a D3 chart that I'm working on (see edited question). Thanks again.

Comment: Make sure you call one of the display methods, such as `.format()` or `.toDate()` or `.unix()`.  Just looking at the raw moment isn't going to work well.  You might also want to do something like `yourmoment.utc().format()` to format it as utc instead of local time.

Comment: Yeah, forgetting that these moments are not immutable gets ya every once in a while. Nice!

Comment: Note to self - `.add(2, 'mins')` silently fails... you want `.add(2, 'minutes')`.

Answer (score 59):

I am working on an application in which we track live route. Passenger wants to show current position of driver and the expected arrival time to reach at his/her location. So I need to add some duration into current time.

So I found the below mentioned way to do the same.
We can add any duration(hour,minutes and seconds) in our current time by moment:

```
var travelTime = moment().add(642, 'seconds').format('hh:mm A');// it will add 642 seconds in the current time and will give time in 03:35 PM format

var travelTime = moment().add(11, 'minutes').format('hh:mm A');// it will add 11 mins in the current time and will give time in 03:35 PM format; can use m or minutes 

var travelTime = moment().add(2, 'hours').format('hh:mm A');// it will add 2 hours in the current time and will give time in 03:35 PM format
```

It fulfills my requirement. May be it can help you.

Comment: It should be 'minutes' not in 'mins'.

Comment: It should be 'minutes' not 'mins'. Or at least it can be 'm'. Please update your answer !

Comment: it's already 'minutes' in my answer and I already mentioned that we can use 'm' instead of 'minutes'(see the comments of answer). I think no need to update my answer.

Answer (score 15):

For people having a `startTime` (like 12h:30:30) and a `duration` (value in minutes like 120), you can guess the `endTime` like so:

```
const startTime = '12:30:00';
const durationInMinutes = '120';

const endTime = moment(startTime, 'HH:mm:ss').add(durationInMinutes, 'minutes').format('HH:mm');

// endTime is equal to "14:30"
```