# Moment.js formatting incorrect date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am very perplexed as to what is going here. Especially since this has been working for some time. I am using v2.10.6.
I am passing in a date string var of `12/02/2015` turning it into a moment object with `moment(eDate,"MM/DD/YYYY");`
I then pass this on to another function that will format it with `eDate.format("dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY")`
which outputs `Wednesday, November 18th, 2015`. See image below.

[image: moment.js formatting weirdness]

Does anyone have insight into this?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with what you've given.  Please update your question to include code that actually reproduces the result you're showing.  If you can, please create a jsFiddle (or similar) as well.

Comment: I might help for us to see the `eDate.format()` function, as it sounds like Moment.js is doing its job just fine.

Comment: Oh - Is `eDate` the string? Or are you creating a moment object called `eDate` first and then passing it into `moment(...)` again?   An exact repro would help here.

Comment: Also, the internal `_d` is showing November 4th, not November 18th.  Neither is what you passed in (showing in `_i`), so there's something wrong with your usage.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't replicate it. @ZackTanner format() is a builtin function moment.js. @Matt yes, edate starts it's life as a string, only passing it to moment once, the 2nd is just to format the output. And about the diff dates, I know, I just do not understand what the problem is. Was hoping someone had some insight without being able to replicate it. Also not entirely sure what the `_d` represents and why it says `Invalid Date`.

Comment: Don't worry about the internal `_` prefixed values.  I was just looking at them because that's all you had shown.  Normally you should not use them.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what was going on. There is a piece of code I recently added and didn't put in the OP cause I thought that it was irrelevant and I assumed wrong. All moments are mutable, there is talk about immutablilty here https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1754. The code I am using was similar to this

```
var theDate = moment(edate,"MM/DD/YYYY"); // edate=12/02/2015 being passed in
_SCHEDULEDPMTDATE = theDate.subtract(cutoff,"days").format("MM/DD/YYYY"); 
// cutoff = 14; i assumed theDate would not be affected.
showNewEventForm(theDate,eventid);

function showNewEventForm(eDate,eid){
    $("#ScheduleDate").text(eDate.format("dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY"));
    // eDate has mutated to eDate-14days
}
```

So you need to use `Moment Clone` http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/moment-clone/ which states `All moments are mutable. If you want a clone of a moment, you can do so explicitly or implicitly.`

My new line should read

`_SCHEDULEDPMTDATE = theDate.clone().subtract(cutoff,"days").format("MM/DD/YYYY");`

Comment: Yes, or implicitly it would be `moment(theDate).subtract....`  Either works.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17334415/634824

Answer (score 0):

So you have discovered the wonders of mutability of Moment objects.

Here is a simpler example that demonstrates what is going on here:

```
var january1 = moment('2015-01-01');
var february1 = january1.add(1, 'months');
var march1 = january1.add(2, 'months');
var april1 = january1.add(3, 'months');
```

Of course `april1` now points to **July 1**. Why not.

If you are one of those people who would expect it to be **April 1** then you may use [**Immoment**](https://github.com/rsp/node-immoment#readme) in place of Moment. It's just like Moment but with less surprises:

```
var january1 = immoment('2015-01-01');
var february1 = january1.add(1, 'months');
var march1 = january1.add(2, 'months');
var april1 = january1.add(3, 'months');
```

Now `april1` points to **April 1** which some people may found slightly less surprising.

### Usage

In browser you can use it like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/rsp/node-immoment/v0.0.12/immoment.min.js"></script>
```

In node:

```
$ npm install --save immoment
```

and:

```
var immoment = require('immoment');
```

or:

```
var moment = require('immoment');
```

if you don't want to change your existing code that already use calls to `moment()`.

### Performance

Immoment is around 3% slower than Moment, see benchmarks:

- http://jsperf.com/moment-vs-immoment

It is about quarter of a kilobyte minified and gzipped.

(Disclaimer: I am the author of Immoment.)