# How to get total hours HH:MM format using Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to calculate the week total time using Moment.js. Please advise.
This is what I tried so far:

```
total = "00:00";
for (var i in json_obj) {

    var timeEnd = json_obj[i].END;
    var timeStart = json_obj[i].START;

    var timeDiff = moment.utc(moment(timeEnd, "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(timeStart, "HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm");
    var res = timeDiff;
    total = moment().add(res);
```

Comment: What are the values of  json_obj[i].END; and json_obj[i].START ?  Are they seconds?

Comment: Need to provide sample input data for anyone to be able to help. If all you have is `"HH:mm:ss"` there is no way to know what day those occurred on. Need full dateTime to do that

Comment: @drj : 06:00:00 its hh:mm:ss format. i have update the question with screenshot

Comment: @charlietfl : pls check updated question with screenshot

Comment: screenshot doesn't do us any good... can't extract data from image. Best thing to do is create a demo with enough data and script dependencies to run your code ... jsfiddle.net , plnkr.co, codepen.io etc can be used

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333425/add-a-duration-to-a-moment-moment-js.. You can use moment().startOf('hour').add(1, 'hours').format('HH:mm') to sum of it

Comment: I think you should use the this approach to do the sum as :

moment({ hour:8, minute:0 })
.add(moment({ hour:6, minute:10 }))
.add(moment({ hour:4, minute:20 }))
.add(moment({ hour:2, minute:40 }))
.format("HH:mm");

------ output ----
"21:10"

Comment: @AjayKumar : im getting time from var timeDiff = moment.utc(moment(timeEnd, "HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(timeStart, "HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm"); how can i extract hours and minites sepratly for adding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what i have achieved with the help of SO and moment.js documentation.

```
var startTime = moment("06:10:00", 'hh:mm');
var endTime = moment("08:00:00", 'hh:mm');

var totalSec = endTime.diff(startTime, 'seconds');

var hours = parseInt(totalSec / 3600) % 24;
var minutes = parseInt(totalSec / 60) % 60;
var seconds = totalSec % 60;

var result = (hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours) + ":" + (minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds);
```

The solution is not wholly implemented with moment but combining old school logic with momentjs.

But this will fulfill your requirement.

OR

To remove old school logic and truly go with moment use below code.

```
var result = moment().startOf('day')
        .seconds(totalSec)
        .format('H:mm')
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f8b49t92/) with both version.

Answer (score -1):

**The best solution which will give the exact result.
Even if your hours will be in 3 digits then it will give the proper result.**

```
const allhours= [
 '5677:40:20',
 '888:30:50'
]
const totalhours = allhours.slice(1)
.reduce((prev, cur) => moment.duration(cur).add(prev),
moment.duration(allhours[0]));
var ms = totalhours ._milliseconds;
var ticks = ms / 1000;
var hh = Math.floor(ticks / 3600);
var mm = Math.floor((ticks % 3600) / 60);
var ss = ticks % 60;


console.log(hh+""+mm+""+ss);
```