# How to add hours to a parse moment date?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I just want to ask if it is possible to add hours to a parse moment date. I have a code like this:

```
var myDate = "2017-04-14 07:07:15"; 
var object_myDate = moment(myDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
var status = object_myDate.add(5, 'hours');
```

but this code gives the following error:

> ```
> object_myDate.add is not a function
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a duration to a moment (moment.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333425/add-a-duration-to-a-moment-moment-js)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[`add`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) is a moment function, you should use on moment object:

```
var myDate = "2017-04-14 07:07:15"; 
var status = moment(myDate).add(5, 'hours').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
```