# moment.js parsing a string 'July 15th 2017, 03:12:09 pm' fromNow()

Tags: reactjs, datetime, momentjs

Not really understanding why my moment.js is returning an invalid date.

I'm trying to return that date as a string into something that returns something like 2 hours from now, or one year ago. But my moment.js keeps returning invalid date.

How would the syntax look like?

Comment: Can you post your code, please? Meanwhile, [something related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17334415/1421957)

Answer (score -1):

import moment from 'moment';

let date = moment().format();

Where `date` returns the today's date