# Adding 1 hour to moment.js object from string

Tags: momentjs

I create a moment object from a string:

```
var scheduled_at = moment($('#event_scheduled_at').val())
console.log(scheduled_at)

> Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2020-05-13 12:00", _f:
> "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
```

Then I want to add 1 hour:

```
var ends_at = scheduled_at.add(1, 'h')
console.log(ends_at)

> Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2020-05-13 12:00", _f: 
> "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm", _isUTC: false, _pf: {…}, …}
```

As you can see it's still 12:00. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried:

```
scheduled_at.add(1, 'h')
console.log(scheduled_at)
```

With the same result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a duration to a moment (moment.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333425/add-a-duration-to-a-moment-moment-js)

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333425/add-a-duration-to-a-moment-moment-js) thread, the `add` function mutates the object it's called on (in this case, `scheduled_at`)